# Route [/admin/update-pwd] not defined

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to change the admin password but it says: Route [/admin/update-pwd] not defined. How do I change it?

controller:

```
   public function changepassword()
{
    return view('admin.changepassword');
}

public function chkPassword(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $adminCount = Admin::where(['username' => Session::get('adminSession'),'password'=>md5($data['current_pwd'])])->count(); 
        if ($adminCount == 1) {
            echo "true"; die;
        } else {
            echo "false"; die;
        }

}

public function updatePassword(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all();
        $adminCount = Admin::where(['username' => Session::get('adminSession'),'password'=>md5($data['current_pwd'])])->count();

        if ($adminCount == 1) {
            $password = md5($data['new_pwd']);
            Admin::where('username',Session::get('adminSession'))->update(['password'=>$password]);
            return redirect('/admin/settings')->with('flash_message_success', 'Password updated successfully.');
        }else{
            return redirect('/admin/settings')->with('flash_message_error', 'Current Password entered is incorrect.');
        }

    }
}
```

blade file:

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('/admin/update-pwd') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PATCH')
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Enter Current Password</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <input type="password" name="current_pwd" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="form2-password" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="input-group-append">
                          <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Enter New Password</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <input type="password" name="new_pwd" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="form2-password" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="input-group-append">
                          <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">Confirm New Password</strong>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <input type="password" name="confirm_pwd" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="form2-password" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="input-group-append">
                          <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    @error('password')
                        <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                    <button type="submit" class="mb-2 btn btn-primary mr-2">Update Password</button>
                  </form>
```

Routes:

```
  Route::get('/admin/changepassword', 'ChangepasswordController@changepassword');
Route::get('/admin/check-pwd','AdminController@chkPassword');
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/admin/update-pwd','AdminController@updatePassword');
```

Comment: Please don't post the same text three times in your question to get around the character limit. The limit exists to encourage you to explain your problem. By posting redundant text to avoid the limit you create extra work for other users - not good.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `route` helper it expects that you provide a route name not a URI, so add this:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/admin/update-pwd','AdminController@updatePassword')
     ->name('admin.update_password');
```

Then in your view you can use:

```
route('admin.update_password');
```

Or use the `url` helper method instead:

```
// instead of this
{{ route('/admin/update-pwd') }}

//use
{{ url('/admin/update-pwd') }}
```

Comment: now error is remoed but when I try to change password then passowrd is not changing it says 404|not found

Comment: Yes, that's because you are matching `post` method to your route but in the form you use `patch` so either remove that directive `@method('patch')` or change it in your `web.php` file.

Comment: i remove @method('patch') from the form but still same

Comment: you can set your app in `debug` mode and share the trace of the error here for more help. 404 means that the route cannot be found, so I don't know what you have changed for it not to work.. It seems like it is hitting an endpoint that does not exist. Can you please share more details?

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/6Lu9RL4RnQMDL82Q4BnzST   currently this is form

Comment: in your `.env` file set `APP_DEBUG=true` and check what is the stacktrace of the error, because I cannot see why it would return 404. As I said 404 is returned whenever the page does not exist.

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/ayE3mhhdnYnJpKThmYSMjY  controller    paste.ofcode.org/YTs3uZ5nJC674j2HCvCw3y   routes

Comment: Well, you have `'AdminController@updatePassword'` and your controller name is completely different :D so change that to be `'ChangepasswordController@updatePassword'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197753/discussion-between-dev-and-nakov).

Comment: changed Route::get('/admin/changepassword', 'ChangepasswordController@changepassword');
    Route::get('/admin/check-pwd','AdminController@chkPassword');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/admin/update-pwd','ChangepasswordController@updatePassword');

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Laravel named route inside your form method. Use [Laravel Named Routed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes), and define it inside your form.

//inside web.php

```
Route::post('/admin/update-pwd','AdminController@updatePassword')->name('admin/update-pwd');
```

Then you will be able to use inside form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('/admin/update-pwd') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```